# How to calculate height of PropertyGrid control?

Tags: c#, winforms

After dynamically creating PropertyGrid and setting its SelectedObject property
I'd like to set its Height property in order to appropriately resize form.

**Update:** Selected object each time can be different depending on some condition, which mean that number of properties can be different and height will vary:

```
var pgd = new PropertyGrid
          {
              SelectedObject = someObject
          };
```

I tried to calculate Height as a sum of its PropertyTabs

```
pgd.Height = pgd.PropertyTabs.OfType<PropertyTab>().Sum(p => p.Height);
```

but 'PropertyTab' does not contain definition for Height.

Comment: `PropertyGrid` doesn't support auto-size. So by assigning a new selected object, size of the control will not change as will remain as what is was. So you can get the height using `propertyGrid1.Height`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei actually in this case SelectedObject can be assigned to different objects with different numbers of properties depending on some condition - so its size will vary each time, so I wanted to set height for PropertyGrid dynamically

Comment: Height will always remain the same, unless you change it. As already mentioned in the first comment, `PropertyGrid` doesn't have any support for auto-size. Just set a suitable `Dock` or `Anchor` for the control and it will show scrollbar automatically if required.

Comment: That is sad, so seems like DataGridView has an advantage, because it supports auto-size, but less suitable for displaying properties of object, will require more coding

Comment: `PropertyGrid` has much better user experience for property editing. It supports categorizing properties, showing icons, description and editing using suitable editors. An auto-sized `PropertyGrid` is not much of use, because if the number of properties are too much, then you need to put it in a scroll-able container, while the control itself supports this feature and shows scrollbar if needed.

Comment: thanks for detailed info and great advice sir, it's very helpful

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
var hgt = pgd.Size.Height;
```

Answer (score 1):

A PropertyGrid control does not resize if you change the SelectedObject property.

It will automatically add a scrollbar if the Height is not sufficient :

[image]

If you need to resize your PropertyGrid you need to put it inside another container and set the Dock property to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to resize the container of the docked or anchored property grid, so that the user does not have to scroll through the list of alphabetical properties, an approximation to the height of the grid area can be made with this code after setting your SelectedObject:

```
int iGridRows = pgd.GetAllGridEntries().Count;
int iGridHeight = (pgd.Font.Height + 3) * iGridRows;
```

...where GetAllGridEntries is a static method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181423/2928659 by [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier).
I will repost that method here for clarity:

```
public static GridItemCollection GetAllGridEntries(this PropertyGrid grid)
{
    if (grid == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("grid");

    var field = grid.GetType().GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (field == null)
    {
        field = grid.GetType().GetField("_gridView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (field == null)
            return null;
    }

    var view = field.GetValue(grid);
    if (view == null)
        return null;

    try
    {
        return (GridItemCollection)view.GetType().InvokeMember("GetAllGridEntries", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, view, null);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It seems that the "3" in the top bit of code is enough to account for the gridlines.

You can account for the other portions of the property grid (Toolbar and Help) before setting the final container height. You can grab the height of the property grid with the container sized such that grid area is collapsed. Then when you set your SelectedObject, just add the calculation above to the height of the container.